# Generate git diff from a list of commits

Tags: git

Given a range of commits such as

```
b9dc80c commit msg 1 #530
88a4d3c another commit
1010bce commit msg 2 #530
040ac6d commit msg 3 #530
6b72683 another commit
ed17416 another commit
f49bbbd commit msg 4 #530
```

I would like to see diff of all changes in commits with `#530`.
So far, I have all the appropriate hashes in a convinient format.

```
git log --oneline | grep #530 | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | xargs echo
# b9dc80c 1010bce 040ac6d f49bbbd
```

Can I somehow "merge" these commits into a one diff? That is, merge in memory, without actually affecting the original repository. I know I can cherry pick those commits in a separate branch and diff that, but that is too complicated.

The use case is that I want to see all changes with the ticket id specified.

example:

```
echo a > file
git add file && git commit "first"
echo b > file
git add file && git commit "second #XX"
echo a > file
git add file && git commit "third #XX"
the-special-command
```

with the "diff" I had in mind, "comparing" `#XX` commits should give empty output rather than two separate changes to `file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

- Script the merge-the-commits-to-temporary-branch dance.
- Use `combinediff` command from [patchutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/) package.

---

Edit: You can simplify the "log | grep" with `log --grep` and ask it for just hashes with `--format`.

Answer (score 0):

Does printing `git show` output for all the commit sha-1s you have found would do the trick for you?:

`git log --oneline | grep #530 | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | xargs git show --oneline`

If you would like to "merge" the output, you would have to extract only unnecessary commit metadata...

or something more "merging friendly":
`git log --oneline | grep a | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | xargs git show --pretty=format:`

Comment: Thanks, though that's not quite what I had on mind. I've updated the original question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
git checkout -b tempbranch b9dc80c
git rebase -i f49bbbd^
# remove all the commits that you don't want from the editor, and
# replace all the other "pick" commands except the first with "squash"
git log -1 -p
```

This creates a new branch that initially contains the same sequence of commits as your current branch. Then, on that branch, the `rebase` will eliminate the commits you don't
want, and squash the rest together into one commmit. Then the `git log -1 -p` step will
show you the resulting patch (you could also use `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` or several other
alternatives that give you slightly different output, depending on exactly what you want
to use the patch for). Note that depending on the nature of the changes in each commit,
you might have to resolve some conflicts during the `rebase`, but that's not necessarily
abnormal...

After you're done with this, you can discard the temporary branch:

```
git checkout otherbranch
git branch -D tempbranch
```

Comment: I suspect this is solving the part that the OP does _not_ need solved. And interactive rebase is definitely no easier than a scripted cherry-pick. The main question is whether the diff can be produced _without temporary branch_.

Comment: @JanHudec You are correct that the `rebase -i` and `cherry-pick` options are similar - they are pretty much doing the same thing on the backend. To me, the requirement for "without temporary branch" seems arbitrary, and unnecessarily complicates the process. The above uses a temporary branch, but deletes it afterward, which is close to the requirement of "not affecting the original repository", as it only leaves behind some loose opjects that will eventually be pruned. My main point was that the end result of the patch is fairly simple to accomplish with `git` alone...

Comment: It's not that arbitrary. Writing temporary objects is not a problem, but merging also involves using the work tree and that means there may be no changes and such. So there are some advantages in not creating a temporary branch.